# Configure multiple registries in .npmrc

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am able to publish and install packages from my internal/private registry by configuring my .npmrc like so:

```
  $ npm config set registry https://mynpm-registry.com
```

However, I would like to configure my .npmrc to proxy out to public https://registry.npmjs.com/, **if the package is not available in my internal regisry.**

I understand that I can potentially configure multiple npm profiles - one for internal and one for external registry - like so:

```
$ npmrc -c my-internal-profile
$ npmrc -c my-external-profile
```

...but this is not what I am looking for.  I would like to have a single .npmrc configuration, with both registries, that will proxy out to the public registry if I don't have a package available in my internal registry.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One way you could do it is scoped packages in your `.npmrc` file.

**Scoped Packages** are simply put as the packages grouped under a namespace. You might have seen `@angular/core` or `@react/something`. So, these are the scoped packages.

In your `.npmrc` file, you could do the following

```
@yourorg:registry=http://localhost:4040/
registry=https://registry.npmjs.com
```

So, this basically means that you everything under @yourorg will be received from your registry, but others are going to be fetched from registry.npmjs.org.

---

If the first option doesn't solve what you are trying to do, you should look into https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/download

This is a registry manager where you can create private registries and create a group of registries (where one of them could be https://registry.npmjs.org). Then for npm, it would look like just a regular call but Sonatype does the heavylifting of :

- If not found in your private registry, it looks to another registry you have mentioned.

Comment: so after this would the package.json be changed or will there be any changes in installation process?

Comment: package.json will not be changed and the installation process would be exactly the same. Instead of fetching the packages from registry.npmjs.org, it will betch from the url of the registry you provide.

Comment: @yourorg will be used nowhere else? how would you tell which packages need to be fetched from this registry

Comment: @SujilMaharjan, I think sonatype repo manager would meet my use case.  Could you point me to the documentation where they explain how to setup npm registries in this way?

Comment: I had to change my npm package to scoped (rename in package.json to @myorg/mycoolpackage) and re-publish it. Then using the @myorg:registry in the .npmrc worked like charm

Comment: Thanks for this awnser, this was driving me crazy! <3